# Recoding missing data

Tags: r, missing-data, recode

I want to recode four NA values in my data to 'missing' or '9999' in order to carryout analysis.  Have tried a number of methods found online to no avail.

```
         data_for_model$imd_grp = fct_collapse(data_for_model$imd,
                                most_deprived = c("1","2", "3"),
                                middle = c("4","5", "6"),
                                least_deprived = c("7","8", "9", "10"),
                                missing = (NA))

         
#data_for_model$imd_grp[data_for_model$imd == 9999] <- NA
```

Comment: `data_for_model$imd_grp[is.na(data_for_model$imd_grp)] <- 9999` or `tidyr::replace_na(data_for_model$imd_grp, 9999)`

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you, the first option works - data_for_model$imd[is.na(data_for_model$imd)] <- 9999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and seemed to work.

```
data_for_model$imd = ifelse(is.na(data_for_model$imd), 9999, data_for_model$imd)

data_for_model$imd_grp = fct_collapse(data_for_model$imd,
                           most_deprived = c("1","2", "3"),
                           middle = c("4","5", "6"),
                           least_deprived = c("7","8", "9", "10"))
```